# Coursera scala assignment objects : week 3 descendingByRetweet

Tags: scala

I am trying to figure out whats wrong in my solution for the coursera Scala course , 3rd assignment. I have figured out everything else , other than the method to convert a TweetSet into a descending tweetList.

Here are the main methods : mostRetweeted for Non-Empty Set.

```
def mostRetweeted: Tweet = {
    val mostRetweetedLeft = left.mostRetweeted
    val mostRetweetedRight = right.mostRetweeted

    if(mostRetweetedLeft != null && mostRetweetedRight!=null)
      if(elem.retweets > mostRetweetedRight.retweets && elem.retweets > mostRetweetedLeft.retweets)
        return elem
      else if(elem.retweets > mostRetweetedRight.retweets && elem.retweets < mostRetweetedLeft.retweets)
        return mostRetweetedLeft
      else
        return mostRetweetedRight
    else if(mostRetweetedLeft == null && mostRetweetedRight!=null)
      if(elem.retweets > mostRetweetedRight.retweets)
        return elem
      else
        return mostRetweetedRight
    else if(mostRetweetedLeft != null && mostRetweetedRight==null)
      if(elem.retweets > mostRetweetedLeft.retweets)
        return elem
      else
        return mostRetweetedLeft
    else
      return elem

  }
```

mostRetweeted for empty Set

```
def mostRetweeted: Tweet = null
```

And finally this method , uses an accumulator to form the list by using the above methods to calculate the most retweeted tweet.

```
   def descendingByRetweet: TweetList = {

          def descendingByRetweet(tweetSet: TweetSet, tweetList : TweetList):TweetList = {

            val mostTweeted:Tweet = tweetSet.mostRetweeted
            // empty set returns null for mostRetweeted method
            if(mostTweeted == null)
              return tweetList
            else {

              descendingByRetweet(tweetSet.remove(mostTweeted),tweetList.add(mostTweeted))
            }

          }
          descendingByRetweet(this,Nil)
}
```

As you might have noticed I added an add method to TweetList
For Nil

```
def add(tweet: Tweet): TweetList = new Cons(tweet,Nil)
```

For Cons

```
def add(tweet: Tweet): TweetList = new Cons(head,tail add tweet)
```

I have also tried some online solutions , but those did not work either.
https://coderwall.com/p/_akojq/scala-week-3
Just like my solution , this gives an "Almost" descending list , but the list is not perfectly descending. Anyways I have spent the entire day and have passed the assignment, so am moving on to the next week.

Comment: Interesting, you give your solution to a problem but never states what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is to convert a tweetSet into a tweetList (list of tweets) , the tweet list need to be ordered in descending order of the number of times a tweet has been retweeted.

Comment: The tweetSet is either "Empty" or has an Tweet object (element) and a left and right "tweetSet" ( each of which can themselves be empty). The tweetList is either a Nil or Cons. The Cons itself has a Tweet and a tail (a tweetList itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `descendingByRetweet` looks correct thought it could be written shorter. I think your problem could be in the `mostRetweeted` method. In this part of the code:

```
if(elem.retweets > mostRetweetedRight.retweets && elem.retweets > mostRetweetedLeft.retweets)
  return elem
else if(elem.retweets > mostRetweetedRight.retweets && elem.retweets < mostRetweetedLeft.retweets)
  return mostRetweetedLeft
else
  return mostRetweetedRight
```

Consider the case where, for example, `elem.retweets = 5`, `mostRetweetedRight.retweets = 0` and `mostRetweetedLeft.retweets = 5`. The return value would be `mostRetweetedRight` which obviously is incorrect. You should add `>=` and `<=` to one of the `if` statements depending on your desired outcome.

Comment: Correct !! Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Thanks.